# Where is the equivalent of /etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ directory in Ubuntu?

Tags: networking, drivers, directory

I am trying to set up a usb gsm Modem. I can't find `/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/` directory to put the driver configuration file into.

In Ubuntu where can i find this directory? I want to put `/etc/sysconfig/networking/devices/ifcfg-Verizon_USB` file wherever it needs to go.

The contents are:

```
ONBOOT=no
USERCTL=yes
PEERDNS=yes
TYPE=Modem
DEVICE=ppp0
BOOTPROTO=dialup
CCP=on
PC=on
AC=on
BSDCOMP=on
VJ=on
VJCCOMP=on
LINESPEED=115200
MODEMPORT=/dev/cellphone
PROVIDER=VerizonQNC
DEFROUTE=yes
PERSIST=no
PAPNAME=qnc
WVDIALSECT=Verizon_USB
MODEMNAME=Modem_USB
DEMAND=no
```

Answer (score 19):

This is an area where the Debian and Red Hat families really differ. Network interfaces in Debian/Ubuntu are not defined by files in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts` (as you have noticed, there isn't even a `/etc/sysconfig` directory), but by `/etc/network/interfaces`. To learn more, check out [the manpage online](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/interfaces.5.html) or run `man interfaces` on your Debian/Ubuntu system.

Comment: In the man page do I find where to put driver configuration file?

Comment: Yes. There is no separate driver configuration file. All network interface settings supported by Debian are configured in the `interfaces` file, in the `iface` statement of that interface.

Comment: Your `ifcfg-Verizon_USB` is in a Red Hat-specific format, you need to convert its meaning into the Debian-specific format.

Comment: Its been a year since i asked this question. Now I'm using wvdial to connect GSM modem. N to be frank i forgot the need why i asked this question. I think setting above configuration will connect my modem through network manager. I'll try it some other tym. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, answering mostly for the benefit of someone who might find this question and have the same trouble. I figured you must have solved it by now. :-)

Answer (score 2):

`/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`, doesnt exist on _buntus. It is under `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections` as 'team-slave-enp0s25.nmconnection' for example, because it uses the newer nmcli and network-manager.